# sql server window function for cumulative sum over a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

just trying to use the window function of doing a cumulative sum against a month as follows.

```
sum(MeterReading) over (partition by Serial, code order by month(MeterReadingDate)) as cumulative
```

this seems to be way to slow to run and doesn't bring any results after waiting, is there something i am doing wrong?

Basically I want to see the sum against each month for each serial/code.

Comment: We will need to see the the full query, some data sample and expected results to tell you if you are doing something wrong

Comment: You also need to partition the results by year. Otherwise, results for April, 2015 will be added to April, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(MeterReading) over (
    partition by Serial,
    code,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, MeterReadingDate), 0)
    order by MeterReadingDate
) as cumulative
```

The function with DATEADD and DATEDIFF converts a date to the first of the month.
Then I add this function to the PARTITION to group by Serial, Code and Month.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd explain the changes you've made along with the example.

Comment: Use a DateDim table; not only will you not have to parse every date but you can combine on a MonthOverAll number that increments month to month from the beginning date, and the sums will always be counted in the right month and year.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
   serial,
   code, 
   DATEPART(YEAR,MeterReadingDate) as Year,
   DATEPART(MONTH,MeterReadingDate) as Month,
    sum(MeterReading) over (
       partition by 
          Serial, 
          code, 
          Datepart(YEAR,MeterReadingDate),
          Datepart(MONTH,MeterReadingDate)
       ) as cumulative
from table
```

First making a sum with an order by claus makes no sense since you want to add all results for one month together.

Second, adding the two dateparts for year and month will partition your data so that the sums only will add meter readings from one month.

If you are interested in seeing yearly variations per month then you can remove the Datepart(YEAR,...) and add some average perhaps.